# AdMob ad banner won't show if there was no connection during first load

Tags: android, admob

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

protected View gameView;
protected AdView adView;
protected RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useImmersiveMode = true;


    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    AdView admobView = createAdView();
    layout.addView(admobView);
    View gameView = createGameView(cfg);
    layout.addView(gameView);

    setContentView(layout);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    admobView.loadAd(adRequest);
}


private AdView createAdView() {
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("**actual_id****");
    adView.setId(R.id.admob);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onAdLoaded();
        }

        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
        }
    });
    //  adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return adView;
}

private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
    gameView = initializeForView(new GameName(), cfg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return gameView;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) adView.resume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) adView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

What's wrong with this code? I tried several things but behaviour is the same. For example, it also won't load ads if Wi-Fi router was rebooted during session until game is closed and reopened as a new process.

Comment: open your logcat and filter with tag Ads to see the log of admob will help us to get the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an AlarmManager or JobManager to schedule a retry of `admobView.loadAd(adRequest)` from within your `onAdFailedToLoad()` method.

You could also check network connectivity before attempting to load your ad and use a `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGED` broadcast receiver to attempt the load once connectivity is returned.

As-is you're only calling `loadAd()` from `onCreate()`.  Having to leave/re-open the app to get the ad to load is to be expected.